# Python - Read a file with strings and integers

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to read a text file in Python containing 4 columns and several rows. This file has strings and floats. But once I load it, this file returns a 2d list that includes only one column of all items in string format.
The output I would like is to have is exactly as the filedemo shows. Note: I need a way that does not require pandas, only lists or NumPy arrays. Any help with this will be much appreciated!

```
filedemo = [['name','name','name'],[1,2,3],['name','name','name'], [4,5,6], ['other','other','other']]
# Using open() #
with open('filedemo.txt') as nkFile:
lines = [line.strip().split() for line in nkFile]
print(lines)
```

**OUTPUT WITH OPEN()**`[['name','name','name'],['1','2','3'],['name','name','name'], ['4','5','6'], ['other','other','other']]`

```
# Using readlines()#
f = open('filedemo.txt', "r")
new = f.readlines()
print(new)
```

**OUTPUT WITH READLINES()**
`[['name,name,name\n'],['1,2,3\n'],['name,name,name\n'], ['4,5,6\n'], ['other,other,other\n']]`

Comment: Is the issue that you want to be using readlines() or that you want the integers to be of type integers in the loaded in list?

Comment: Could you please show us your `filedemo.txt` contents?

Comment: I think you should just convert every element of every second sublist to `[float(element) for element in sublist]`. Is that not what you would want?

Comment: It seems that your two examples are inconsistent with the actual content of the file. For example, in the first example you use `split()` on each line which separates by whitespace, but with the `readlines()` methods we see that only commas are separating the strings. Why not just showing the structure of the file itself with the data from `filedemo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear exactly what filedemo looks like. And I suspect your `split()` command should really be `split(',')`. So I'm assuming that filedemo is this:

```
name,name,name
1,2,3
name,name,name
4,5,6
other,other,other
```

And I'm assuming your problem with your `open...nkFile` solution is that the numbers remain strings when you're done.

Here is a brute force way to go through `lines` and clean it up:

```
lines = [['name','name','name'],['1','2','3'],['name','name','name'], ['4','5','6'], ['other','other','other']]

for i, innerlist in enumerate(lines):
    for j, item in enumerate(innerlist):
        try:
            lines[i][j] = int(float(item))
        except ValueError:
            continue
            
print(lines)
```

which gives this as output:

`[['name', 'name', 'name'], [1, 2, 3], ['name', 'name', 'name'], [4, 5, 6], ['other', 'other', 'other']]`

This code tries to convert every entry in your nested list into an integer. If it fails with a ValueError, we ignore and continue. This solution uses the (very handy) enumerate function to give the index and item of every element in a list.

Answer (score 0):

When we read any file in Python it reads into string datatype. If we want to assign appropriate data after reading data start using ast.literal_eval() method.

```
data = ast.literal_eval('[['name','name','name'],['1','2','3'],['name','name','name'], ['4','5','6'], ['other','other','other']]')
```

Output will be a list datatype

> [['name','name','name'],['1','2','3'],['name','name','name'], ['4','5','6'], ['other','other','other']]